# How to check the review status and report of your extension submitted to publish on Microsoft Edge Add-ons?

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension, browser-addons, microsoft-edge-chromium

I submitted my extension to publish on Microsoft Edge Add-ons website. As per their documentation it takes 7 or less business days to publish. Now I have a few questions -

1. Will I be notified that my extension is published?
2. If it does not publish, how can I know the reason for not publishing? Is there anyone from Microsoft
   to communicate that or any report shared for the same and where?
3. Where should I reach out to get help with extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the [submission states for extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/submission-states) in the Partner Center.

You can contact Microsoft Edge extension support according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/contact-extensions-team).

Answer (score 0):

Review reports capturing the success or failure details of the extension review process are sent to extension developers via email once it is complete.

You will also be able to access the review report directly from the partner center after logging in. A report will be included on the extension overview page that includes submission status.

Information on recommended updates and failure reasons will be provided if the extension did not pass certification.

Please submit a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/supportrequestform/e7a381be-9c9a-fafb-ed76-262bc93fd9e4) if you have any issues with your extension's registration or publishing.

Thank you!